# How can i test tilt efftect? - IPhone Simulator

Tags: iphone, ios-simulator, effect, tilt

I am trying to write a game. That game uses tilt effect, but i don't know how to test it on Iphone Simulator 3.0. 
I search it on internet, but the result is zero. How can i...?

Answer (score 13):

Short answer: You can't, not directly. You have to use a real device.

Longer answer: You could subclass `UIAccelerometer` and do as you like. You could simulate input, or write a client and server pair that sends acceleration information from a real device to your app running in the simulator, or from your Macbook's accelerometer if you fancy waving your laptop around.

Answer (score 2):

Try https://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/. It does the same thing as iSimulate -- it sends accelerometer events from the phone to your computer -- but it's free and open source.

Answer (score 1):

There's an application in the AppStore called [iSimulate](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=306908756&mt=8) which lets you feed an actual device's accelerometer inputs into the sim. You do need to have a device for testing.

Answer (score 1):

ON a related note, you can also capture accelerometer data from safari running on your iphone/ipad
See this demo http://www.webdigi.co.uk/blog/2012/using-an-ios-device-to-control-a-game-on-your-browser/

Answer (score 0):

Just saw this when asking a similar question - you can actually set the interface orientation now in the new xcode, so even though you can't 'tilt' it directly, you can make it to where it only supports landscape - then it will load the landscape view in the emulator!  :D

Answer (score -3):

From: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator/InteractingwiththeiOSSimulator.html

1. Place the pointer where you want the rotation to occur.
2. Hold down the Option key.
3. Move the circles that represent finger touches to the start position.
4. Move the center of the pinch target by holding down the Shift key, moving the circles to the desired center position, and releasing the Shift key.
5. Hold down the mouse button, rotate the circles to the end position, and release the Option key.

Comment: That's for two-finger touch gestures, not tilt (accelerometer/gyroscope) input.