# Can i test accelerometer effect in Xcode simulator?

Tags: iphone, iphone-5, ios5

I am working on an app that manages the alpha property of image views. Alpha property can increase/decrease as the user moves the phone. I saw something on here about using a subclass of UIAccelerometer. Can anyone help me to do this so that I can test it on simulator?
Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yo cant test it using simulator, you should use real device for testing accelerometer.
Check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593270/how-can-i-test-tilt-efftect-iphone-simulator), it may help you.

Answer (score 7):

You can "capture" accelerometer data coming from a real device.

You can purchase [iSimulate](http://iosdevelopertips.com/tools/isimulate-testing-multi-touch-events-accelerometer-movements-using-xcode-simulator.html)

here:
http://bobueland.com/cocos2d/2011/how-to-install-isimulate/

..or

you can use a **free solution**: [accelerometer-simulator](https://code.google.com/p/accelerometer-simulator/wiki/Home)

More about how to install or tutorial:

- http://builtby.me/2012/07/howto-use-the-accelerometer-in-the-iphone-simulator/
- http://builtby.me/2012/07/iphone-accelerometer-visualizer/
- http://myfirstiphoneapp.co.uk/2011/07/receiving-accelerometer-data/

Answer (score 5):

You can't test Accelerometer feature on Xcode simulator.

For this, see following on apple's site.

[Limitations of Testing in iOS Simulator](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/TestingontheiOSSimulator/TestingontheiOSSimulator.html)