# I can't add accelerometer using Swift in Xcode 6

Tags: swift, accelerometer

I'm trying to start the accelerometer for a game I'm making using the new Swift programming language, but it doesn't seem to work. This is my code right now:

```
var motionManager=CMMotionManager()
var queue=NSOperationQueue()
motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = (1/40)
motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdatesToQueue(queue, withHandler {(accelerometerData:CMAccelerometerData!, error:NSError!) in
    self.update(accelerometerData.acceleration)
})
```

I'm not getting any errors, but when I run this nothing happens (my update function isn't called). What exactly is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

Is the accelerometer available? check if `motionManager.accelerometerAvailable`
is false. Maybe you just don't have it the the device you're running on.

Note that you should use something like `1.0/40.0` for the interval to be what you expect.

if you use the simulator you can't test the accelerometer. See in [Can i test accelerometer effect in Xcode simulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16542200/can-i-test-accelerometer-effect-in-xcode-simulator)

Answer (score 0):

Your `motionManager` and `queue` are local variables, so the objects are deallocated at the end of this function. Store them somewhere, like in an instance variable.  I've made a similar mistake a bunch of times myself.