# iOS simulator gesture with mouse/ trackpad

Tags: ios, ios-simulator

Is there is any way to add **mouse and trackpad's gesture** like scrolling in simulator screen.

Comment: try **holding down the option key** - there are various key combos

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you would have to create a Mac app that got these events and then translated them to what the simulator was expecting

This project:

https://code.google.com/archive/p/accelerometer-simulator/

Tries to do something similar but with the accelerometer (since MacBooks have one).

This answer links to some tutorials that show you how to do what that project is doing: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16558215/3937